# Least-squares when some coefficient is $0$?

Tags: least-squares

I'm trying to find least squares approximation $p(x)=c_1x+c_2x^2$ of $f(x)=xe^{x/2}$ in $[0,2]$.

Using the algorithm here, p.7.:
http://www.math.niu.edu/~dattab/MATH435.2013/APPROXIMATION.pdf

I'm able to come up with a $3 \times 3$ matrix $S$ and $3 \times 1$ vector $b$. However this gives me as a solution three coefficients, even though I only have two. What do I need to do to get only two (i.e. no $c_0$)?

Comment: Why don't you compute the linear approximation $c_1 + c_2x$ to $f(x)/x=e^{x/2}?$

Comment: @gammatester Why? What I wrote is what I'm asked to do.

Comment: Is this your interpretation? What is the exact taks? If you shall use quadratic polynomials you have to live with computed $c_0\ne 0$. If I should do it I would use my suggestion or setup/solve the corresponding normal equations with the basic functions $x, x^2,\;$ but I would **not** use quadratics.

Comment: @gammatester The assignment is what I wrote in the first line.

Comment: @gammatester Using your proposed method, do I then define a new function $g(x)=f(x)/x$ and proceed using the same algorithm as I did above?

Comment: Not exactly, because you would have a $2 \times 2 $ system.

Comment: @gammatester But isn't that what I'm looking for?

Comment: I don't know. But I guess then you would not have a zero coefficient (the Taylor series at $x=0\;$would be $xe^{x/2} = x + x^2/2 + o(x^3)$

Comment: @gammatester Care to elaborate that? Why?

Answer (score 0):

The approximation is 
$$
g(x) \approx c_{1} f_{1}(x) + c_{2} f_{2}(x)
$$
over the domain $a < x < b$. Choose the method of least squares. Minimize the sums of the squares of residuals:
$$
 r^{2}(c) = \int_{a}^{b} \left(f(x) - c_{1} f_{1}(x) - c_{2} f_{2}(x) \right)^{2} dx.
$$
This creates the linear system
$$
\begin{align}
%
 \mathbf{A} c &= G \\
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \int_{a}^{b} f_{1}(x) \times f_{1}(x) dx & \int_{a}^{b} f_{1}(x) \times f_{2}(x) dx \\
    \int_{a}^{b} f_{2}(x) \times f_{1}(x) dx & \int_{a}^{b} f_{2}(x) \times f_{2}(x) dx 
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
   c_{1} \\ c_{2}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
&=
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \int_{a}^{b} f_{1}(x) \times g(x) dx \\
    \int_{a}^{b} f_{2}(x) \times g(x) dx
  \end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
$$
In this problem $g(x) = xe^{\frac{x}{2}}$, $f_{1}(x) = x$, and $f_{2}(x) = x^{2}.$

For the domain $a= 0$ and $b=2$, the linear system is 
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{8}{3} & 4 \\
 4 & \frac{32}{5} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
   c_{1} \\ c_{2}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
=
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{r}
   8 (e-2) \\ -32 (e-3)
  \end{array}
\right],
$$
which has the solution
$$
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
   c_{1} \\ c_{2}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
=
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    24 (-19 + 7 e) \\ 300 - 110 e
  \end{array}
\right].
%
$$
The following plot shows the residual error function $g(x) - c_{1}x - c_{2}x^{2}.$

[image: Input function - trial function]